# Error en WordPress al intentar buscar o cargar temas

Tags: wordpress-theme

Soy nuevo en **WordPress** y luego de instalarlo y ponerlo a correr me sale un error que salta justo cuando intento buscar algún tema o cargarlo para personalizar mi sitio.

Sucedió un error inesperado. Puede que algo vaya mal con *WordPress.org* o la configuración de este servidor. Si sigues teniendo problemas, por favor prueba en los foros de soporte.

Eso es lo que me dice cuando estoy en *localizar/wordpress/wp-admin/theme-install.php?browser=featured*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando intento modificar algo del tema predeterminado del 2017 me dice esto:

No se pudo crear el directorio wp-content/uploads/2017/12. Asegúrate de que el servidor tiene permisos de escritura para el directorio superior.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías hacer es en el archivo **class-http.php** que se encuentra en la **wp-includes** modificar la clave **sslverify** a false

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola sabes que coloque sslverify en false pero no ocurrio nada...

Intente cargar un thema ya descargado aparte y mira lo que me salio 

No se pudo crear el directorio wp-content/uploads/2017/12. Asegúrate de que el servidor tiene permisos de escritura para el directorio superior.

Comment: En que sistema operativo estas ejecutando el servidor web?

Comment: en **fedora 27**

fijate intente subir una imagen cualquiera para sustituir la imagen de cabecera de 2017 y me salio esto.

No se pudo crear el directorio wp-content/uploads/2017/12. Asegúrate de que el servidor tiene permisos de escritura para el directorio superior.

Comment: Creo que el problema esta en los permisos de tu servidor

Con esta linea lo puedes arreglar si no me equivoco

sudo chown $USER:www-data -R /var/www/directorioRaizWordPress


Si no te sirve busca en algún foro sobre permisos apache2

Answer (score 0):

**Solución**
Bueno, despues de investigar bastante y tambien gracias al comentario de Eugeni Bejan pude encontrar lo que hacia falta... solo tenia que darle permisos suficientes

en el directorio /var/www/html ejecute el comando **chown -R apache.apache wordpress/** y ya pude personalizar mi sitio de WordPress.